# Motion tracking goes way off

Tags: motion-detection, google-project-tango

So I've been messing around with Project Tango, and noticed that if I turn on a motion tracking app, and leave the device on a table(blocking all cameras), the motion tracking goes off in crazy directions and makes incredibly wrong predictions on where I'm going (I'm not even moving, but the device thinks I'm going 10 meters to the right). I'm wondering if their is some exception that can be thrown or some warning or api call I can call to stop this from happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you block all the camera, there is not features camera can capture.
so motion tracking may be in two stages: 
1. No moving, 
2. drifting to Hawaii.

either ways may happen. 
If you did block the fisheye camera, yes, this is expected.

For API, There is a way to handle it.
Please check life cycle for motiontracking concept

For example for C/C++ :
https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/c/c-motion-tracking

if API detected pose_data as TANGO_POSE_INVALID, the motion tracking system can be reinitialized in two ways. If config_enable_auto_recovery was set to true, the system will immediately enter the TANGO_POSE_INITIALIZING state. It will use the last valid pose as the starting point after recovery. If config_enable_auto_recovery was set to false, the system will essentially pause and always return poses as TANGO_POSE_INVALID until TangoService_resetMotionTracking() is called. Unlike auto recovery, this will also reset the starting point after recovery back to the origin.

Also you can add Handling Adverse Situations with UX-Framework to your app.
check the link:
https://developers.google.com/project-tango/ux/ux-framework-exceptions

The last solution is by write the function handle driftting by measuring velocity of pose_data and call TangoService_resetMotionTracking() and so on.

Comment: thank you for the links and detailed answer. I assume I get the velocity by doing the velocity formula (displacement/time) and there is no actually API call to get the object's velocity?

Answer (score 0):

I run a filter on the intake that tries not to let obviously ridiculous pose changes through, and I believe no reported points whose texel is white nor any pose where the entire texture is in near shouting distance of black

Comment: Right now I'm just ignoring any pose data when the xyzIj.xyzCount is less than 500. I assume that what you mean when you say "whose texel is white"?   Also that makes sense if pose data is a lot more or less than the previous point I'll ignore that. Thanks

Comment: No, white texels means that the point on the picture corresponding to the 3D cloud point is white -  I run logic that tries to cut down on the error that comes from strong IR sources like windows on a sunny day - it would be better if Google would let us have the IR image